# «Ребёнок не умеет сморкать нос». Профсленг?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, жаргон

Эта фраза ― из беседы с прилично русскоговорящим врачом. Можно ли говорить так (в два слова), и чем вызвана потребность так говорить, на ваш взгляд?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стала относить выражение "сморкать нос" к профсленгу, оно известно и используется давно:

СМОРКАТЬ, сморкнуть; сморгать, *зап., пск.* извергать из носу мокроту.
*Нянька ему **носа не сморкает**, не утирает. **Сморкай** всяк свое **нюхало**.*
Толковый словарь Даля. В.И. Даль. 1863-1866.

[**Малый академический словарь**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/64936/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C) приводит это словосочетание вообще отдельно:
**сморкать нос**
то же, что сморкаться.
*[Сергей Петрович] принялся **сморкать** свой длинный и правильный **нос*** (Тургенев. Дворянское гнездо).

В толковом словаре Ожегова говорится:
﻿СМОРКА́ТЬ, -аю, -аешь; несовер., что.
Резким выдыхательным движением очищать (нос) от слизи.
*Сморкать нос. Сморкать кровь из носа.*

Получается, что говорить "сморкать нос" можно. Потребность же употребления "в два слова", мне кажется, связана с [**этимологией**](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), с уточнением: какое именно действие нужно производить — очищать нос (не втягивать, не глотать, не шмыгать).

Comment: Согласен со всем кроме последнего абзаца. В одно слово — "сморкаться" — ясно и понятно: ни втягивать, ни глотать, ни шмыгать это не может означать.

Comment: Нянька ему носа не сморкает... Это не про то, увы. А Малый академический и словарь Ожегова фиксируют, и, как известно, это не печать качественности на выражении. Получается, что вывод — <так говорят>, а не <так можно говорить>, — делается на литературном источнике. Спасибо.

Comment: Ушаков вообще утверждает: СМОРКА́ТЬ, сморкаю, сморкаешь, несовер. (к высморкать) (разг.). Только в выражении: сморкать (сморкаю, сморкаешь и т.д.) нос - то же, что сморкаться (сморкаюсь, сморкаешься и т.д. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1031394/СМОРКАТЬ

Comment: Понятно, что совместно с носом: сморкать другим местом на голове не принято, как и вообще другой частью тела. Вот и вопрос: нет ли тут коварной иронии, указывающей на тавтологию или, как тут говорил Aer, избыточность?

Answer (score 1):

Сморкать нос — устоявшееся выражение, тождественное глаголу *сморкаться*.

Глагол *сморкать* переходный, управляет винительным падежом (*что?*). Сейчас, кажется, он употребляется редко, разве что в профессиональной беседе, однако раньше был в ходу: см. примеры из Тургенева.

Малый академический словарь, равно как и словарь Ожегова, является нормативным, то есть отражает нормы литературной речи. Следовательно, говорить так можно.

Comment: Можно, но вопрос: что заставляет так говорить?

Comment: @shampar я написал: глагол *сморкать* переходный. Это вполне нормально, что при нем стоит прямое дополнение. Ну а что заставляет так говорить... видимо, говорящий либо слышал это выражение где-либо, либо читал классическую/специальную литературу... Боюсь, никто не сможет дать точный ответ )

Comment: Спасибо. Полагаю, честь мундира, статус, педантичность, дистанция в отношениях с пациентами.

Comment: @shampar возможно! Про тавтологичность (скорее, про избыточность): ее тут нет; в устоявшихся выражениях она отсутствует, ср.: дарить подарок, видеть видео, писать письмо...